# Read a list of INT type from the console and print out only even numbers out of the given list Using list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm very new to functional programming with Haskell, I have started learning it a few days ago by doing a few tasks.

I'm trying to write a function that will Read a list of INT type from the console and print out only even numbers out of the given list Using list comprehension. This is what I have:

```
[x | x <- [nums], x == even, x <= 50]
```

Comment: Hi there buddy, and welcome to StackOverflow. This sort of question really does not belong here, since there are many tutorials you can find via a simple google search which will help you get started with Haskell. Take care and good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but basically none of your code is right (except for `[x | x <-` maybe).

Comment: I suggest that you break your requirements into smaller pieces: 1. A function that takes a list of integers and returns a list of only the even integers from that list. 2. A function which reads a input and returns a list of integers. Write a `main` function that uses these two functions. Once you get something that works, you can iterate on it to simplify it all into a single list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

What you have written has a couple of minor errors:

```
[x | x <- [nums], x == even, x <= 50]
```

1. `x <- [nums]` will bind `x` to each element of the list `[nums] :: [[Int]]`, which has one element, `nums :: [Int]`. Presumably you wanted `x <- nums`, so that `x :: Int`.
2. `x == even` attempts to compare `x`, which has type `Int`, to the function `even`, which has type `Integral a => a -> Bool` (or, simplified a bit, `Int -> Bool`). You can’t compare values of different types for equality, nor can you compare functions; what you want to do is *call* the function `even` on `x` with `even x`.

With those changes, your expression will work without error:

```
[x | x <- nums, even x, x <= 50]
```

Now, as for reading the values from the console, you would do that from `main` since it requires `IO`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter space-separated list of numbers."
  line <- getLine
  let nums = map read (words line) :: [Int]
  print [x | x <- nums, even x, x <= 50]
```

This uses `words` to split the line on whitespace, `map read` to convert each string in the resulting list to an `Int`, and finally your list comprehension to calculate the output. Now, input such as `10 25 30 45 50 60` will produce output such as `[10,30,50]`.

A couple of exercises to improve your understanding:

- Move the prompt, parsing, and list comprehension into separate top-level function definitions with type signatures.
- What happens when the user enters invalid input like `10, 20, foo`? How could you handle this error?